# Left-border won't move

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The vertical border is too close to the '10' in step 10. How can the left border be moved to the right so that is there is some space to the right of the big '10' before the vertical border?

```css
.custom-counter {
    list-style-type: none;
/*    list-style-type: decimal !ie; /*IE 7- hack*/
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 3.5em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
     
    counter-reset: li-counter;
}

.custom-counter > li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    min-height: 3em;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.5;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.custom-counter > li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1em;
    width: 0.8em;

    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
 
    content: counter(li-counter);
    counter-increment: li-counter;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>Step 1</li>
  <li>Step 2</li>
  <li>Step 3</li>
  <li>Step 4</li>
  <li>Step 5</li>
  <li>Step 6</li>
  <li>Step 7</li>
  <li>Step 8</li>
  <li>Step 9</li>
  <li>Step 10</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Horrible css. Look here -> https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a `margin-left` on the `li` tag (as needed) and then change the `left` attribute suitable. Like so:

```css
.custom-counter {
    list-style-type: none;
/*    list-style-type: decimal !ie; /*IE 7- hack*/
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 3.5em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
     
    counter-reset: li-counter;
}

.custom-counter > li {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    min-height: 3em;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.5;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.custom-counter > li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1.2em;
    width: 1em;

    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
 
    content: counter(li-counter);
    counter-increment: li-counter;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>Step 1</li>
  <li>Step 2</li>
  <li>Step 3</li>
  <li>Step 4</li>
  <li>Step 5</li>
  <li>Step 6</li>
  <li>Step 7</li>
  <li>Step 8</li>
  <li>Step 9</li>
  <li>Step 10</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why are you setting additional styles, hardcoded in px, instead of modifying the existing margins and positioning?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.custom-counter {
    list-style-type: none;
/*    list-style-type: decimal !ie; /*IE 7- hack*/
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 3.5em;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
     
    counter-reset: li-counter;
}

.custom-counter > li {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    min-height: 3em;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.5;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.custom-counter > li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;

    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
 
    content: counter(li-counter);
    counter-increment: li-counter;
}
```

```html
<ol class="custom-counter">
  <li>Step 1</li>
  <li>Step 2</li>
  <li>Step 3</li>
  <li>Step 4</li>
  <li>Step 5</li>
  <li>Step 6</li>
  <li>Step 7</li>
  <li>Step 8</li>
  <li>Step 9</li>
  <li>Step 10</li>
</ol>
```

Lines that are changed are inside .custom-counter > li::before. ***left*** from -1em to 1.2em and ***width*** from 0.8em to 1.2em so it lines up well.